# Why there is extra space at the bottom of the masterpage?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, custom-masterpage

I have placed a button which Hides/Shows SharePoint ribbon `onclick`. So initially when the page is loaded the ribbon gets hidden. Due to which there is an extra white space below every page which uses that masterpage.
So I want to remove those extra white spaces.

Till now i have tried

changing the height of `s4-workspace` like this

```
$("#s4-workspace").css("height", "643px");
```

This works when there is 1-2 app parts but does not works on each and every screen or when there is more app parts or no app parts.

Also I have tried giving percentage to height.

So there any general way to solve this issue.

[image: Extra space at the bottom of master page]

Comment: Use sticky footer CSS solution that pushes footer to the bottom of the window no matter the content height.

Comment: how about using Height as "auto"

Comment: I can't use sticky footer I will try using height as `auto`

Comment: Height `auto` is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting the height of #s4-bodyContainer

Comment: @cptasker:  Its not working